# Problem creating a Directory object in Oracle

Tags: oracle, object

The code is this:

Originally:(http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/FTPFromPLSQL.php)

The approach uses a combination of the UTL_TCP and UTL_FILE packages to create a simple FTP API (ftp.pks, ftp.pkb). Once the API is loaded into the appropriate schema simple FTP commands can be initiated as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_docs AS '/u01/app/oracle/';
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
@c:\ftp.pks
@c:\ftp.pkb


-- Send an ASCII file to a remote FTP server.
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_conn := ftp.login('ftp.company.com', '21', 'ftpuser', 'ftppassword');
  ftp.ascii(p_conn => l_conn);
  ftp.put(p_conn      => l_conn,
          p_from_dir  => 'MY_DOCS',
          p_from_file => 'test_get.txt',
          p_to_file   => '/u01/app/oracle/test_put.txt');
  ftp.logout(l_conn);
END;
/
```

The problem is that when I try to create the directory object I get an error saying that Create symbol wasnt expected.

where this line should be created?

Comment: Syntax for directory creation is absolutely correct. Could you please provide error stack to define the problem more precisely?

Comment: What tool do you use ? this is a SQL*Plus script, it may not work with other SQL clients as is.

Comment: Just to be sure, your database is on a Linux/Unix system, right? That is, `/u01/app/oracle/` is a valid location on your file system?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything preceding the create statement line in your script? It looks like there might be something you left off the post.